# Show LLDP neighbors history

Tags: switch, aruba, lldp

Is that possible to view the logs or history of a lldp neighbors, I just want to review a switch if the switch once connected to another switch.

Answer (score 2):

No, not on Aruba/HPE switches. You'd need to have debug logged LLDP events (creating quite a mess likely) or polled the neighbors via SNMP. Otherwise, past information is lost.